# UIAlertView to UITableViewController

Tags: iphone, uitableview, xcode4.3, uialertview

When I press the 'OK' button at the `UIAlertView` I wanted it to go back to  `UITableViewController` but when I click it doesn't go back.

`QuizViewController.h`:

```
@interface QuizViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> { 
}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;

@end
```

`QuizViewController.m`

```
-(IBAction)buttonWasClicked:(id)sender{

UIButton *resultebutton= (UIButton*)sender;

if (qCount < totalQuestions) {

    id prevQuestion =  [appDelegate.qs objectAtIndex:qCount-1];
    NSString * correctAns = [prevQuestion labelAns];

    if ([correctAns isEqualToString:resultebutton.titleLabel.text]) 
        myScore += 5;            

    NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", correctAns);
    NSLog(@"The button title is %@ ", resultebutton.titleLabel.text);

    NSString *finishingStatement = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your score so far is %i!", myScore];
    theScore.text = finishingStatement;



    id nextQuestion = [appDelegate.qs objectAtIndex:qCount];

 quizLbl.text = [nextQuestion labelQn];
    headerLbl.text = [nextQuestion labelHeader];

 [qBtn setTitle:[nextQuestion labelBtn] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [qBtnB setTitle:[nextQuestion labelBtnB] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [qBtnC setTitle:[nextQuestion labelBtnC] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 [qBtnD setTitle:[nextQuestion labelBtnD] forState:UIControlStateNormal];



 qCount++;

 }


 else {

     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Results" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your total score will be %i!", myScore]
                                                    delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];

     [alert show];


 }

}

-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    QuizTableViewController *quizTable = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"quizTable"];

    [self.navigationController presentModalViewController:quizTable animated:YES]; 
}
```

Comment: assign delegate:self....

Comment: i've changed that but it still doesn't work, it there any errors besides that?

Comment: try [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Comment: try logging alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex: to see if its getting called, Im assuming the QuizViewCOntroller was pushed on the stack and then you wanted to pop it after tapping the ok button of the alert, use [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES]; why are you presenting a modal on the alerts' delegate if you wanted to go back :/

Answer (score 0):

You should not declare a delegate method in your .h file like:
 `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;`
instead give the delegate:self in alertView like this:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Results" message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your total score will be %i!", myScore]
                                                    delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

and declare  in your .h file like

```
@interface QuizViewController : UIViewController<UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

and then use `[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:quizTable animated:YES];` 
in your delegate method at the click of button.index=0.

Comment: The `delegate:self` part is important, but none of the other three suggestions would stop his alert handler from working: declaring the callback in the header is unnecessary, but doesn't hurt, declaring that you implement `UIAlertViewDelegate` is unnecessary, and he only has one button, so `buttonIndex` will always be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        if([alertView.title isEqualToString:@"the_title_of_your_alert"]){
           //above line is to identify your alert, if you have several ones
           if(buttonIndex == 0)
               //do this
           else if (buttonIndex == 1)
               //do that
           else if //bla bla bla, find the button, and if it is your "ok" button, 
                   //go to your TableViewController
        }
    }
```

And alertView's delegates should not be declared that way, just implement the delegate methods.

Comment: i only have one button, do i still need to use if else method?

Comment: Release your alert object as soon as you have shown it. And when you alloc the alert object, say "delegate:self", not "nil".

Comment: that means that you are doing something wrong, beyond the posted problem

Comment: If he's using ARC (which most people are by now), then he most definitely should **not** release the alert as soon as he has shown it.  I don't see any other `release` or `autorelease` calls in the code.  Also, he only has one button, so there's no `if-else` that applies for his `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:`

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't get called back is that you set your `UIAlertView` delegate to `nil`.  It needs to be set to `self` in order for that object to receive a callback when the alert is dismissed:

```objc
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Results"
                                                message:[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Your total score will be %i!", myScore]  
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
```

Comment: i've changed it, but it still doesn't work. i have only 1 "OK" button.

Comment: @jaspanther, I'm not sure I understand your comment.  You have only 1 "OK" button, because that's all you created in the line above.  If you want more buttons, you have to add them via the `otherButtonTitles` parameter.  If for some reason you are responding concerning **other** peoples' comments about your `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` method ... **no**, it's not necessary to have an `if` statement if you only have 1 button.  Please provide some more information.  What is not working?  Is your `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex:` still not getting called?

Comment: @otakuProgrammer, did you mean to post this comment elsewhere?  maybe under the question?

Comment: sory about that i meant to comment to the question i transfered it already

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to go back.

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```